# How prevent os to refresh the video memory

Tags: c#, c++, driver, video-card

I need to implement an application which can freeze the screen image while, at the same time, all the application work as normal, except they are not reflected on the screen.

It may need to prevent all the applications to write data into the video card memory.

Some one told me to try CUDA programming, but it only works on Nivida video card, and I need my program to be suitable for all kinds of video cards.

I don't know if there is any API about video card drivers that can help.

The function of the program is really very simple, but I don't have any clue.

Should I work into driver programming ,or video drivers already provided such kind of api for programmers?

Should I directly deal with the hardware or just use the provided api (if there is one)?

The program will run on the platform of windows, but the hints from linux also would be fine (maybe they are my inspiration).

Comment: Would it be easier to make a normal full-screen Windows application that takes a screenshot when it starts, and then just displays that screenshot on its full-screen window?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This may be a lot more easier, but I'm afraid other applications may jump to the top level of the z-axis. It would be better to implement the function by controlling video memory or video port. However, in fact, I'm not sure if I'm right that wasting my time to choose a harder way.

Comment: Considering the computer your software runs on is (normally) not yours, and your software is just an app like the others (and not "above the others"), I (as user) can think some suspicious thing is happening and drop your software. Unless you are writing a sw for a dedicated system, don't embark into this kind of things... They will always look "odd" to users.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is surely a part of a dedicated system. It seems I still have a long way to go~

Comment: Your client is clearly pretty clueless about what's technically possible.  Any programmer has the right to take advantage of that, charging an arm and a leg for an hour of work.

Answer (score 3):

You can cheat:

- App makes a screenshot of the screen
- App creates a topmost window big as all the screen
- App shows the screenshot

There are easy methods to do all the three things.

Probably you'll have to do some tests for multi-screen setups (this will probably be the most difficult thing, because there are various "modes" for multi-screen)

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact my client asked to implement the function by   controlling GPU. It seems if I can't find a way to do this, I have to try to persuade him to use your method. And also, I intuitively think it won't be to hard to follow client's request, although now I know nothing about the filed.

Comment: @sparrow In general the problem (a problem) is to make your app able to write to the screen and interact with the user. There are some ways you could use to block the other apps... (for example you could write a filter driver to the graphical adaptor, but then it wouldn't be able to distinguish your output from the other apps output, and it would be difficult to make it DirectX "resistant"... Or you could program your entire app as a screensaver (screensavers are executed on another "virtual screen"), but then you couldn't receive input.

Comment: Maybe I need to write a filter driver to finish the work, but I know nothing about driver programming. Can you give me some clues?

Comment: @sparrow No :-) And if you don't have a clue, a video driver is the last place you want to go. You must be this high to go to that luna park's attraction...

Comment: Thanks again! I will try to find out the solution.